# Exporting AVI Videos from Adobe Flash CS6 using an automated script (JSFL)

Tags: adobe, flash-cs6, jsfl

I have a bunch of .fla CS6 files that I need to export to avi (after setting up the resolution, compression settings etc) manually. I am wondering if this can be achieved via a JSFL script or similar.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the [JSFL Reference](https://help.adobe.com/archive/en_US/flash/cs5/flash_cs5_extending.pdf): `document.exportVideo()` is what you're after:

from the docs:

> **Usage** 
>   exportVideo( fileURI [, convertInAdobeMediaEncoder] [, 
>   [ transparent] [, stopAtFrame] [, stopAtFrameOrTime] )
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `fileURI` A string, expressed as a file:/// URI, that specifies the
>   fully qualified path to which the video is saved.
>
> `convertInAdobeMediaEncoder` A boolen value that specifies whether or
>   not to send the recorded video to Adobe Media Encoder. The default
>   value is true, which sends the video to Adobe Media Encoder. This
>   parameter is optional.
>
> `transparent` A boolean value that specifies
>   whether or not the background should be included in the video. The
>   default value is false, which includes the movie background in the
>   video. This parameter is optional. stopAtFrame A boolean value that
>   specifies whether the video should be recorded until it reaches a
>   certain frame or a specific time. The default value is true, stop when
>   a certain frame is reached. This parameter is optional.
>
> `stopAtFrameOrTime` If stopAtFrame is true, this is an int specifying
>   the number of frames to record. If stopAtFrame is false, this is the
>   number of milliseconds to record. The default value is 0 which, if
>   stopAtFrame is true, will record all the frames in the main timeline.
>   This parameter is optional.
>
> Returns Nothing.
>
> **Description Method**;
>
> exports a video from the document and optionally sends it to Adobe
>   Media Encoder to convert the video
>
> **Example**
>
> The following example illustrates the use of this method:
>   `fl.getDocumentDOM().exportVideo("file:///C|/myProject/myVideo.mov");`

I can't remember if that is in AVI format, however you should be able to convert the video. Setting the second parameter (`convertInAdobeMediaEncoder`) to `true` should send the video to Media Encoder for conversion, however it will be a lot less straight forward to automate that (very convoluted, but [not impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450387/cs5-5-import-video-through-jsfl-without-video-wizard/7477495#7477495))

Alternatively I would recommend looking into exporting a PNG sequence that you can then convert to any video format you would like with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) or similar tools, baring in mind you could trigger the conversion process from JSFL (via `FLfile.runCommandLine` for example).

In short:

- use the JSFL reference (e.g. `document.exportVideo()`, etc.)
- prototype with a simple through away script and a short timeline
- test/fix/clean/comment code for the full version of the script after all your questions are answered by prototypes